# Generating random integer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to generate a random integer. When I enter a number in a textbox and call the function by clicking on a button, it says "The number was undefined", instead of giving the value of the generated number. Here is my code:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random(max-min+1)+min);
}

var array=[];
var integer=getRandomInt(1,100);
var broj=array[integer];
```

Comment: In your current code, `array` is empty, so `array[integer]` will always be undefined, no matter the value returned by `getRandomInt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
var array=[];
function genRateNumber(){

var integer=Math.floor(getRandomInt(1,100));
array.push(integer)
console.log('array :'+array)
console.log('current Genrated  Value:'+integer)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="genRateNumber()">genrate number</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is empty. You need to push your generated value:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random(max-min+1)+min);
}

let array=[]; // here array is empty
let integer=getRandomInt(1,100);
let broj=array.push(integer);
console.log(integer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var integer1=getRandomInt(1,100);
console.log(integer1);
```